# How to sort an object array

Tags: c++, sorting, oop

I've created a class called `Box` that is pretty much what it sounds like.  I want to sort these box objects, and I have created a function to do so.

```
void boxSort(Box array[], int size) {
    Box temp;
    bool swap;

    do {
        swap = false;
        for(int count=0; count<(size-1); count++) {
            int volume1 = array[count].getVolume(array[count].height, array[count].width, array[count].length);
            int volume2 = array[count+1].getVolume(array[count+1].height, array[count+1].width, array[count+1].length);
            if(volume1 > volume2) {
                temp = array[count];
                array[count] = array[count+1];
                array[count+1] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    }
    while(swap);
}
```

This function sorts an array of objects of class `Box`.

`Box` class:

```
class Box {
    public:
        double height, width, length;
        double getVolume(double, double, double);
        double getSurfaceArea(double, double, double);
        void setHeight(double);
        void setWidth(double);
        void setLength(double);

        Box() {
            height = width = length = 1;
        }
        Box(double h, double w, double l) {
            setHeight(h);
            setWidth(w);
            setLength(l);
        }
};

#endif

void Box::setHeight(double h) {
    height = h;
}

void Box::setWidth(double w) {
    width = w;
}

void Box::setLength(double l) {
    length = l;
}
double Box::getVolume(double h, double w, double l) {
    double volume = h*w*l;

    return volume;
}
double Box::getSurfaceArea(double h, double w, double l) {
    double surfaceArea = (h*w)*2 + (h*l)*2 + (l*w)*2;

    return surfaceArea;
}
```

When I run this program I get an error:

> linker command failed with exit code 1

This doesn't shown up on any particular line, and I have no idea what it means, so I'm a little lost on how to debug this.

Comment: Why didn't you use `std::sort`?

Comment: Also, I doubt, that this is the whole error message. Please tell us, how you compile / link your code, the complete error message and try to provide a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve)

Comment: I have to use a bubble sort

Comment: `getVolume` and `getSurfaceArea` shouldn't take parameters, they should use the member variables.

Comment: The title ("How to sort") and the question ("How can I debug a linker error") have nothing in common.

Answer (score 0):

The linker errors are reported if you have any problem with libraries or object files linked.  Were you able to successfully build the executable?

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is occurring due to more than one main() function in your code.You can have only one main() function.

Comment: I do not have multiple main functions.

Comment: are you including any .cpp file in other .cpp file?. normally we don't include a cpp file in other cpp file. This is done by  including .h files. check in your header files if you are including a header file more than once directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the error. But I would suggest changing `boxSort` function to something like this.

change `getVolume` to this

```
double Box::getVolume() {
    return height*width*length;
}
```

and boxSort to this

```
void boxSort(std::array<Box, 3> boxes)
{
        struct
        {
                bool operator()(Box x, Box y)
                {
                        return  x.getVolume() < y.getVolume();
                }
        }compFunc;

        std::sort(boxes.begin(), boxes.end(), compFunc);

        for(Box a: boxes)
        {
                std::cout<<a.getVolume()<<" ";
        }

}
```

function call:

```
std::array<Box,3> boxes = {box1, box2, box3};
boxSort(boxes);
```